# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/beanutils/BeanMap

Tags: java, runtime-error, apache-commons, apache-commons-beanutils

I am trying to use below code for comparing two object values and print the mismtach:

```
  BeanMap map = new BeanMap(ep);
  PropertyUtilsBean propUtils = new PropertyUtilsBean();
  for (Object propNameObject : map.keySet()) {
     String propertyName = (String) propNameObject;
     Object expectedValue = propUtils.getProperty(ep, propertyName);
     Object actualValue = propUtils.getProperty(ap, propertyName);
     if (!expectedValue.equals(actualValue)) {
        WorkloadGeneratorLogger.log("> " + propertyName
              + " is different (oldValue=\"" + expectedValue
              + "\", newValue=\"" + actualValue + "\")");
     }
  }
```

Getting below error while using beanMap:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/beanutils/BeanMap

.....................

Caused by java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanMap

Below is my pom.xml entries for the same:

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

Not sure what is being missed here,I tried the same combination of jars suggested by below link:

[java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/collections/Transformer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28778191/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-org-apache-commons-collections-transformer)

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/dependencies.html

Still unable to sort this out.

Comment: How are you launching the program?

Comment: I am creating a jar of this project and running it on diff system

Comment: I would try unzipping the jar and checking if it contains commons-beanutils... Apart from that I don't know, sorry

Comment: how to you create the jar? do you include the libs into your jar file?

Comment: jar was missing on other machine and i was not including the lib in jar file

Comment: this link may be helpful. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17907382/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-com-sun-org-apache-commons-beanutils-propertyuti

Comment: so problem is solved?